# Шифрование ключей сессии

Tags: хеширование, hashcode

Вопрос конечно же может показаться некорректным, но я откровенно уже и не знаю где искать.

Суть вот в чём: Есть ли какие-то правила или методологии хеширования ключей сессии в базе данных. И целесообразно ли подобная операция вообще? Если да, то почему и по каким принципам. Если нет, то хотелось бы тоже узнать почему и зачем? Буду признателен любой информации по этой теме. П.С. гугл меня знает как родного. Туда можно не отсылать. :)

Comment: Похоже вы все таки не совсем родной для гугла [тынц](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/136122/how-to-secure-store-sessions-values-in-webapps)

Comment: Спасибо! 
В целом статья помогла. Но, если есть что-то ещё по этой теме, то буду признателен.